# Pagination and Sorting - custom sorting of data

Tags: spring, database, sorting, pagination

I have a problem with sorting data in my project.

Since I implemented pagination I don't know how solve this issue.

Before pagination I fetched whole list of entities and sort it by this class:

```
    public class EntitySorter {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(EntitySorter.class);

    public static int sort(String s1, String s2) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(s1) || StringUtils.isBlank(s2)) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (!s1.contains("/") || !s2.contains("/")) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).length() != 4 ||
                s2.substring(s2.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).length() != 4) {
            return -1;
        }

        final String year1 = s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        final String year2 = s2.substring(s2.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        if (!NumberUtils.isDigits(year1) || !NumberUtils.isDigits(year2)) {
            return -1;
        }

        final int result = NumberUtils.toInt(year1) - NumberUtils.toInt(year2);

        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        }

        final String caseNumber1 = s1.substring(0, s1.indexOf("/"));
        final String caseNumber2 = s2.substring(0, s2.indexOf("/"));

        if (!NumberUtils.isDigits(caseNumber1) && NumberUtils.isDigits(caseNumber2)) {
            try {
                final int intCaseNumber1 = Integer.parseInt(caseNumber1.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
                return intCaseNumber1 - Integer.parseInt(caseNumber2);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return -1;
        }
        if (NumberUtils.isDigits(caseNumber1) && !NumberUtils.isDigits(caseNumber2)) {
            try {
                final int intCaseNumber2 = Integer.parseInt(caseNumber2.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
                return Integer.parseInt(caseNumber1) - intCaseNumber2;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return -1;
        }
        if (!NumberUtils.isDigits(caseNumber1) && !NumberUtils.isDigits(caseNumber2)) {
            try {
                final int intCaseNumber1 = Integer.parseInt(caseNumber1.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
                final int intCaseNumber2 = Integer.parseInt(caseNumber2.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
                return intCaseNumber1 - intCaseNumber2;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return -1;
        }

        return NumberUtils.toInt(caseNumber1) - NumberUtils.toInt(caseNumber2);
    }
}
```

Let's take some example:

We have a list of IDs:

```
101/2021
102/2021
1/2022
86/2020
```

Correct sorted list is:

```
1/2022
102/2021
101/2021
86/2020
```

In database this ID is one column. It's not split to number and year. I tried to use Sort.by() but I didn't make a success. How can I use pagination and keep correct sorting?

Answer (score 0):

For pagination to work optimally, the data should be indexed correctly..

If there is a different representation of the data you can use with one column then it's the best way.

If not then the easy way would just to decompose one column to multiple columns, create a multi column index and sort by these columns + you need to understand if the natural ordering of the columns fits your logic.

The hard way would be to create user defined function and index on it and other solutions, but I would avoid the unnecessary complexity.

Keep it simple!